# EF inserting object to DB getting validation error

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am trying insert into database my model with relation one to many:

I have two models:

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }     

    public virtual Country Country { get; set; }
}

public class Country
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string CountryName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
}

User user = new User()
{
     Name = model.Name,
     Surname = model.Surname,  
     Country = new Country { Id = 1 }
};
```

When I try to insert it to the database I get exception

> *Validation failed for one or more entities.*

The `CountryName` field is required (`CoutryName` column is required in database)

I don't want each time call to database to get full Country object, any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of instancing a new country, do something like this:

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }     
    public int CountryId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CountryId")]
    public virtual Country Country { get; set; }
}

public class Country
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string CountryName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
}

User user = new User()
{
     Name = model.Name,
     Surname = model.Surname,  
     CountryId = 1;
};
```

This explicitly sets the CountryID on the User.

Comment: I want to reduce these round trips to DB, and get the job done in one call.

Comment: Well you could set the Country ID explicitly.  This assumes you know the CountryID at run time.  This will work with a one to one or one to many, but not a many to many.

Answer (score 0):

You should use "FK Associations" instead "Independent Associations" this is create article about it:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/efdesign/archive/2009/03/16/foreign-keys-in-the-entity-framework.aspx